# RESTful two-part verification API

Tags: rest, side-effects

I'm designing a RESTful website ownership verification API, and I'd like to do it in an idiomatic manner.

As it stands currently, a user `POST`s a verification request. The server responds by creating a verification resource which contains a URL with a random token embedded in it. The user is then supposed to add the token URL to their site, verifying that they do indeed control the site. My server then checks that the URL exists on their site.

A response to the `POST` may look something like this:

```
{
 "id": 21,
 "link": "http://mydomain.com/api/v0/verifications/21/",
 "created": "2014-05-06T22:11:44.086Z",
 "domain_name": "http://theusersdomain.com",
 "verified": false,
 "token": "34jfdusdcflkanmlkdfjnsakdfhmv",
 "token_url": "http://theusersdomain.com/mydomain-34jfdusdcflkanmlkdfjnsakdfhmv"
}
```

The part I'm having trouble with is how the user should tell the server that they updated their site, and that the server should go check that the token URL exists. I've thought about using an empty `PUT`/`PATCH` request. However this seems like a bit of a hack, seeing as the user isn't really updating a resource, but instead triggering side-effects which do.

Another possibility I thought of is having the user update the `verified` field with a status of `true`. However, this also seems awkward. Seeing as their update isn't what's changing the field's value, but instead a side-effect is.

The main issue I'm having isn't so much an implementation problem, but figuring out how to do it in an idiomatic fashion.

So what's an idiomatic way of going about a two part verification like this with a REST API?

Comment: You could get the site to send the token in every request in one of the headers